# Working with a text editor for julia language in Windows OS

Tags: windows, julia

Hey i am new in the coding area. And i want to know how can i load a code part that wrote with a text editor(Sublime) in Julia .I am working on windows OS and i do not know how can i run a code part. I load julia 1.1 but i dont want to code row by row. I want to a code part and then run it somewhere but i dont know how can i do these process and their term names.Briefly ican say that i want to generate a sparse matrix and vectors many density and sizes elements and then i want to multiple them. Could u explain step by step what should i do and which way i should go. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is the Sublime Text Plugin [SendCode](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/SendCode) which allows you to send pieces of code from Sublime to, for example, the Julia REPL by pressing CTRL+Enter (or Shift+Enter to send a whole block). Just follow the installation and usage instructions on their webpage.